# Accessing Eclipse 4 Services from CallbackHandlers (like in Equinox Security)

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, equinox, e4

I followed the [example](https://wiki.eclipse.org/RAP/Equinox_Security_Integration) on how to use Equinox Security (which acts as a Bridge to JAAS) with Eclipse RAP. This sample is rather old and it makes use of the old 3.x platform.

I now tried to port it to Eclipse 4. So inside Eclipse 4 I do not have Singletons anymore like PlatformUI. This caused me trouble when accessing my Application Model from inside the CallbackHandler.
The Sample dummy login module and the callback handlers are both registered via extension points and instantiated inside the Equinox Security bundle via reflection.

So I do not have access to the instances and can not inject the Eclipse 4 Services or the Eclipse Context. In consequence I can not make any contributions to the UI from the callback handler.

So maybe in a more generic manner the question could be either:

**1)** How to access the e4 context/services from already instantiated objects which were created by 3rdParties via reflection?

**2)** Does anyone has another suggestion to make the [sample](https://wiki.eclipse.org/RAP/Equinox_Security_Integration) work on e4?

Thanks in advance.

Cheers
Sascha

Comment: `EclipseContextFactory.getServiceContext(bundleContext)` provides static access to an `IEclipseContext` which can access some services (but not everything).

Comment: This seems to be a good hint, greg. Will give it a try. Thx

Comment: I could manage it to get the EPartService with it. But due to timing issues I can not get my Part via getObject(): The retrieved object is null until it is rendered but I need data from the CallbackHandler instance for rendering (in my case User/PW prompt). I now solved it via static methods:

The Part contains some static setters to set the data for the prompts. These are called from CH when it is started (CH is always started first). When we come to rendering these data is already set and the part is rendered by using this data. Hope to find a better solution in future.